# Disqus include causing Bad Gateway errors

Tags: 7, comments

I've set up Disqus on my drupal site and it was previously working, but it's suddenly not working and I have no idea what changed.

This is one of my nodes with Disqus in the block at the bottom:
http://liberalgeek.com/content/republican-todd-akin-and-legitimate-rape-doesnt-cause-pregnancy

I'm getting a 502 Bad Gateway message in my javascript console on Chrome:

```
GET http://mediacdn.disqus.com/1345491156/uploads/themes/dsq028ee724157b05d04e7bdcf237d12e60.css?1557 502 (Bad Gateway) client.js:6
DISQUS.requireStylesheet client.js:6
Backbone.View.extend.bootstrap client.js:84
Backbone.View.extend.initialize.b client.js:81
b.Events.trigger lib.js:108
(anonymous function) client.js:16
```

Comment: Which version of the Disqus module do you have installed? http://drupal.org/project/disqus/  I see several 404 errors on Disqus elements from that url as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the API was undergoing maintenance which is why it was rejecting with a 5xx error. Here is the list of meanings to the HTTP response codes that Disqus uses:

http://disqus.com/api/docs/errors/